Why Do LLMs Generate Repetitive Outputs During Text Generation?
I'm working on understanding why large language models (LLMs) sometimes produce repetitive outputs when generating text. For example, in tasks involving explanations or lists, the model might repeat the same phrase or structure multiple times.
Here’s an example I encountered (simplified):
"In few-shot learning, we can use it for text classification, and few-shot learning can also be used for text summarization, and few-shot learning can be applied to..."

My Observations and Questions:

What factors in the decoding process (e.g., beam search, sampling,
or temperature) contribute to this behavior?
Could biases in the training data cause this repetition, or is it primarily a result of the model's context-aware prediction mechanism?
Are there specific techniques or decoding adjustments (e.g., repetition penalties, modifying temperature) that have worked well to reduce this issue?

What I’ve Tried:

Experimented with increasing temperature and top-k sampling but
still saw some improvement only in certain contexts.
Adding more diverse prompts, but the issue persists in outputs with similar
sentence structures.

I’d appreciate insights, suggestions, or links to relevant research or best practices!

These are all possible factors for this behavior. This doesn't sound like a production LLM, is it your local Llama3.1-70B-Instruct LLM?

No, it's not a local Llama3.1-70B-Instruct LLM. It's the production-ready version hosted on Hugging Face Chat, so it is indeed a live and operational model.
